# How to blindly raise an event in a base class without calling it from the derived class

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class

Given the following abstract class and a derived class:

```
public abstract class Worker{
   public bool DoingWork {get;set;}
   public abstract void DoWork();
}

public class MyWorker : Worker{

   public override void DoWork(){
    // do all the work in here..
    // currently setting the base classes DoingWork property at the start and end of work
   }
}
```

Is there a mechanism that would allow me to raise an event in the `abstract` when an implemented `DoWork()` method is called, without having to code the derived class to implement or call any additional methods.

The reason for the question is that I would like to raise an event when any of the implemented `DoWork()` are called, and finished and removing the need for the implementations to set any flag in the base class.

Comment: you're looking for the [Template Method / Template Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern).  Define flow in the base, and defer some implementation to subclasses.

Comment: @Jonesopolis - thank you, will read more on that pattern now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the caller is calling the derived class's method, no.  If you want the base class to control what's going on you'll want to have the consumer calling a base class method, and then simply have the derived class override the behavior that you want *without* making that the method that the caller calls by making the overridden method `protected`.

```
public abstract class Worker
{
    public bool DoingWork { get; set; }
    private event Action WorkCompleted; 
    public void DoWork()
    {
        DoingWork = true;
        DoWorkImplementation();
        DoingWork = false;
        WorkCompleted?.Invoke();
    }
    protected abstract void DoWorkImplementation();
}

public class MyWorker : Worker
{
    protected override void DoWorkImplementation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you. Seems so obvious now :D